# promtail how to discover kubernetes cluster name

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I installed promtail with helm chart
helm install promtail -f values.yaml grafana/promtail
I want add one extra scrape_configs in values.yaml

```
config:
  clients:
    - url: https://loki-test.net/api/prom/push
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: kubernetes-pods
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
          regex: "gke-(.+?)-.+"
          target_label: cluster
```

But scrape_configs unfortunatelly isn't merged with default scrape_configs.
I want discover cluster name for handy searching logs in grafana.

Default scrape_configs

```
kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_controller_name
        regex: ([0-9a-z-.]+?)(-[0-9a-f]{8,10})?
        action: replace
        target_label: __tmp_controller_name
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_name
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app
          - __tmp_controller_name
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: app
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_instance
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_instance
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: instance
      - source_labels:
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app_kubernetes_io_component
          - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component
        regex: ^;*([^;]+)(;.*)?$
        action: replace
        target_label: component
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: node_name
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: namespace
      - action: replace
        replacement: $1
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - namespace
        - app
        target_label: job
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: pod
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: container
      - action: replace
        replacement: /var/log/pods/*$1/*.log
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_uid
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: __path__
      - action: replace
        regex: true/(.*)
        replacement: /var/log/pods/*$1/*.log
        separator: /
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_kubernetes_io_config_hash
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_kubernetes_io_config_hash
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
        target_label: __path__
```

How to merge default scrape_configs with scrape_configs from values.yaml?
Or another option how to discover kubernetes cluster name?